# Capital S in file permissions

Tags: permissions, chmod

I issued the command

```
sudo chmod 700 <directoryname>
```

in the hopes of getting the permissions for that directory to look like `drwx------`

Instead, they look like `drwx--S---`

Why does this happen and how do I go about removing the `S`?

Comment: @jasonwryan: I don't think this is a dupe; exeleon is concerned about the fact chmoding didn't **remove** the S, and I'm with them on that one.

Comment: Similar question here http://serverfault.com/questions/238962/how-do-i-clear-the-s-permission-on-a-directory-in-linux